Doubt regarding poles and essential singularity
Actually I always try to check type of singularity by checking the limit...
I know for pole at $z_0$ $\lim_ {z\to z_0}f\left(z\right)=\infty$ and for essential singularity the limit does not exist...
Actually this part is often confusing whether should I say limit does not exist or is infinity.
So incase of $f(z)=1/\sin z$ I am not getting whether should I say the limit does not exist at $z=0$ or is infinite...since as $z_0\to 0$, $\sin z$ will also tend to zero so limit must be infinite hence should be a pole.
Am I correct...for this explanation of pole...
And can you please give an example where limit does not exists not infinite and hence it is essential singularity...

Try $e^{1/z}$ as $z\to 0$.

Are you familiar with Laurent series expansions?

Asserting that $\lim_{z\to a}f(z)=\infty$ means that, for each $M>0$, there is some $\delta>0$ such that, when $|z-a|<\delta$, then $|f(z)|>M$. It then follows from the fact that $\lim_{z\to0}\sin z=0$ that $\lim_{z\to0}\frac1{\sin z}=\infty$.
However, you can easily check that $\lim_{z\to0}e^{1/z}$ doesn't exist.
